# SQL : choose newest time for data using MAX

Tags: postgresql, join, time, nested, max

So I have 2 tables. First table was named "name" :

```
| uploadID  | Name | Freq |
---------------------------
| upload123 |  A   |  12  |
| upload345 |  A   |  12  |
| upload678 |  A   |  12  |
```

and second one was named "upload" :

```
| uploadID  | uploadDate | uploadTime |
---------------------------------------
| upload123 | 2016-03-05 | 17:04:33 |
| upload345 | 2016-03-05 | 13:05:00 |
| upload678 | 2016-02-03 | 12:12:12 |
```

I want to do a query the one with newest date and time . the expected result is :

```
| uploadID  | Name | Freq |
---------------------------
| upload123 |  A   |  12  |
```

because upload123 has the newest date and time.
I tried :

```
SELECT * from name 
join upload
on name.upload id =upload=upload id 
where uploadDate = (SELECT MAX(upload.uploadDate) from upload) 
and uploadTime =(SELECT MAX(upload.uploadTime) from upload)
```

It result nothing. But when I dont use the uploadTime, It works but return me 2 rows with same Date. I think I made a mistake when using aggregate function MAX to uploadDate. But I cant figure it out. Im using postgreSQL and the data type for uploadTime is TIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*,s.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.upload_id ORDER BY s.uploadDate DESC,s.uploadTime DESC) as rnk
    FROM name t
    JOIN upload s
    ON(t.upload_id = s.upload_id)) p
WHERE p.rnk = 1
```

The problem with your query is that the maximum `time` not necessarely belongs to the maximum `date` .

```
| upload123 | 2016-03-05 | 17:04:33 |
| upload345 | 2016-02-05 | 18:05:00 |
```

Here `2016-03-05` is the maximum date, and `18:05:00` is the maximum time.